# Laravel Updates restock from 0 to 1 in database if stock is equal to minimum stock

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-10, inventory-management

How do I automatically update the restock value if my stock is the same as the minimum stock then the value is 1 and if not the value is 0?
What section is the code logic written in?

I use Laravel 10

This is the migration database code

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('product_name');
            $table->string('category_id');
            $table->string('unit_id');
            $table->string('product_code')->nullable();
            $table->double('min_stock');
            $table->double('stock');
            $table->integer('restock')->default(0)->comment('0=No, 1=Yes');
            $table->string('product_image')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

This is the controller code if there is stock out

```
public function updateOrder(Request $request)
    {
        $order_id = $request->id;

        // Reduce the stock
        $products = OrderDetails::where('order_id', $order_id)->get();

        foreach ($products as $product) {
            Product::where('id', $product->product_id)
                    ->update(['stock' => DB::raw('stock-'.$product->quantity)]);
        }

        Order::findOrFail($order_id)->update(['order_status' => 'complete']);

        return Redirect::route('order.completeOrders')->with('success', 'Order has been completed!');
    }
```

This is the controller code if there is incoming stock

```
public function updatePurchase(Request $request)
    {
        $purchase_id = $request->id;

        // after purchase approved, add stock product
        $products = PurchaseDetails::where('purchase_id', $purchase_id)->get();

        foreach ($products as $product) {
            Product::where('id', $product->product_id)
                    ->update(['stock' => DB::raw('stock+'.$product->quantity)]);
        }

        Purchase::findOrFail($purchase_id)
            ->update([
                'purchase_status' => 1,
                'updated_by' => auth()->user()->id
            ]); // 1 = approved, 0 = pending

        return Redirect::route('purchases.allPurchases')->with('success', 'Purchase has been approved!');
    }
```

I haven't tried it because I'm still confused

Comment: > if my stock is the same as the minimum stock then the value is 1 and if not the value is 0 <<<=== write out exactly what you need done at which time. That sentence is really really confusing. Minimum stock of 0? Strange. First write it out, then program it. There's no shame in putting comments in your code and then program that piece that you've just explained in that comment

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.